# Data.table join with index delivers unexpected results if indexed column name is a prefix of the join column name

Tags: r, data.table

For a specific set-up of two data.tables a join does not deliver the results I am expecting. Am I making a mistake in my code or could this be a data.table problem?

Please have a look at the example below.

```
library(data.table)

# In the code below the join does not deliver the result I would expect
DT1 <- data.table(colname=c("test1","test2","test2","test3"), colname_with_suffix=c("other","test","includes test within","other"))
DT2 <- data.table(lookup=c("test1","test2","test3"), lookup_result=c(1,2,3))
DT1[colname_with_suffix == "not found", ]  # automatically creates index on colname_with_suffix
DT1[DT2, lookup_result := i.lookup_result, on=c("colname"="lookup")][]
# PLEASE NOTE: same result with slightly different syntax: DT1[DT2, lookup_result := i.lookup_result, on=c(colname="lookup")][]
# colname  colname_with_suffix lookup_result
# 1:   test1                other         NA
# 2:   test2                 test         NA
# 3:   test2 includes test within         NA
# 4:   test3                other          3


# Expected result:
 # colname  colname_with_suffix lookup_result
# 1:   test1                other          1
# 2:   test2                 test          2
# 3:   test2 includes test within          2
# 4:   test3                other          3
```

For the following variations the join works as expected. The unexpected behaviour above seems to be occurring only, if an index exists on a column having a column name being the prefix of the join column name and both having similar text contents.

```
# For all following alternatives the join delivers the correct result

# (a) Same data tables as above, but no index
DT1 <- data.table(colname=c("test1","test2","test2","test3"), colname_with_suffix=c("other","test","includes test within","other"))
DT2 <- data.table(lookup=c("test1","test2","test3"), lookup_result=c(1,2,3))
DT1[DT2, lookup_result := i.lookup_result, on=c("colname"="lookup")][]

# (b) Index on DT2, but completely different values in indexed column than in join column
DT1 <- data.table(colname=c("test1","test2","test2","test3"), colname_with_suffix=c("other","other","other","other"))
DT2 <- data.table(lookup=c("test1","test2","test3"), lookup_result=c(1,2,3))
DT1[colname_with_suffix == "not found", ]  # automatically creates index on colname_with_suffix
DT1[DT2, lookup_result := i.lookup_result, on=c("colname"="lookup")][]

# (c) Index on DT2, similar values in indexed column, but indexed column name is not a prefix of join column name
DT1 <- data.table(colname=c("test1","test2","test2","test3"), x.colname_with_suffix=c("other","test","includes test within","other"))
DT2 <- data.table(lookup=c("test1","test2","test3"), lookup_result=c(1,2,3))
DT1[x.colname_with_suffix == "not found", ]  # automatically creates index on x.colname_with_suffix
DT1[DT2, lookup_result := i.lookup_result, on=c("colname"="lookup")][]
```

SessionInfo:

```
# R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
# 
# locale:
#     [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    
# 
# attached base packages:
#     [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
#     [1] data.table_1.10.0
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#     [1] tools_3.3.2
```

Please note that the same behavior occurs for data.table 1.10.4 and R.Version 3.4.2 under Windows and also Ubuntu Linux 14.04.

Comment: @akrun Your opinion? I can reproduce the problem on R3.3.2 (64 bit on Windows) with data.table 1.10.4. Strange thing: When I remove the auto-generated key with setindex(DT1, NULL) the join is working correctly again. It looks like a bug in data.table but I cannot find a related issue (github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues).

Comment: BTW: Removing the quotation marks from the LHS of `on=c("colname"="lookup")` does not solve the problem..

Comment: Yes, I think it's a bug. Simplest example would maybe be `DT1 <- data.table(colname=c("test1","test2","test2","test3"), colname_with_suffix=c("other","test","includes test within","other")); setindex(DT1, "colname_with_suffix"); DT1["test2", on=.(colname)]` Btw, @RYoda you can't ping akrun from here unless he's commented or edited this post.

Comment: Thank you very much, RYoda and Frank. I have just opened an issue at github: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2465

Answer (score 1):

[This has been fixed in v1.11.0](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#bug-fixes-1) by @MarkusBonsch (answering this so it won't be in the unanswered list)